# Event ID 1014 DNS Client Events

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8, dns

I recently installed Windows 8 Pro on my laptop (upgraded from Windows 7 Professional). Ever since the upgrade, I've had DNS resolution problems after my laptop wakes from sleep.

I checked the Event Viewer and found that, after I wake my laptop from sleep, the system logs event 1014 (DNS Client Events). The problem is temporarily fixed after a reboot.

I tried to fix this issue by following the steps in [this article](http://bit.ly/T7Cg7T), but that did not resolve the issue.

Any ideas??